# How to check if EEPROM.read(0) contains a value

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-ide

I would like to read a data from `EEPROM.read(0);` on my `esp32`. But before reading I would like to check if there is a value at 0 position and if not, take the default predefined one.

I did some searching, but I could not found what `EEPROM.read(0);` returns if there is not a value to write an if statement.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMRead

Comment: So the answer is 255. Thanks!

Comment: But what if the value you ultimately write is 255? Bit of a problem there. You'll have to ensure you never ever write 255.

Comment: Thanks for a good opinion! I'm trying to save there a Temperature value in Celsius, I hope it will never reach 255 degrees >.<

Comment: But temperatures of -1C aren't unheard of, and -1 almost certainly flips to 255 as an unsigned byte. A wee bit of caution is still required. Two's compliment is not your friend here.

Comment: yup, I already added a check to not go bellow 18 and above 254. This temp value will be set by user no sensor, so I'm not losing a data with this check